# How can I use the incubating Vector API from Kotlin in a Gradle build?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, vector, compiler-flags

I want to use the new Vector API from a Kotlin project using a Gradle build.

I tried this:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
    kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("--add-modules", "jdk.incubator.vector")
}
```

Result is:

```
Invalid argument: --add-modules
```

I've checked and the right SDK is being used, and help for *javac* at least shows `--add-modules` as a valid flag, so what I guess is going on is, this is the *Kotlin* compiler, and I need to provide a different flag, or some kind of prefixed flag to add a module to the classpath. What is the magic incantation here?

Comment: `--add-modules` might be a valid `javac` flag, but these `freeCompilerArgs` are indeed for the `kotlinc` compiler. That said, I don't know of a way to add modules like this (and I don't see anything in [Kotlin compiler options](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/compiler-reference.html#kotlin-jvm-compiler-options)). But I never personally looked too much into Java modules tbh, maybe someone else can help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin compiler's argument for this is named [`-Xadd-modules`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.7.0/compiler/testData/cli/jvm/extraHelp.out#L8). You can pass it in this way:

```
kotlinOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xadd-modules=jdk.incubator.vector")
```

(Note that right now there is a bug [KT-54288](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-54288/No-error-is-reported-on-using-JDK-incubator-modules) which incorrectly makes this compiler argument unnecessary. So until it's fixed, you can get away without adding it to the build.)